# React native navigation headerTitleAlign has no "right" option

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Recently i been trying to align the header of my title in the right side, but for some reason im not provided with an option to align the title right, only center and left(both are working). The default alignment is left.
Is there another way to align the title right?

[image]